# not output after program was run?

Tags: c, input, output, executable

I am very confused to why my program isn't running well. I am connected to a server through my windows PC using PuTTY. It always works fine but something weird is going on I believe.
Here's the code for identify.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        char word[256];
        int i;
        int validity = 1;

        scanf("%s", word);

        for(i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                /* First character should only be underscore or a letter */
                if(word[i]!= '_' && !isalpha(word[i]))
                {
                    validity = 0;
                    break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                /* Rest can be Alpha-numerics or underscore */
                if(word[i]!= '_' && !isalnum(word[i]))
                {
                    validity = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if(validity)
            printf("valid\n");
        else
            printf("invalid\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the input file for testing if a name is a possible identifier name or not. identitytest.txt :

```
name

name2

2name

_name

__name

na_me

@name

na-me
```

I then upload both files to my server using FileZilla.

I then do the following command to make identify.c executable:

```
gcc identify.c -o identify
```

Executable has been created.
Then I run the following command:

```
identify <identifytest.txt >output.txt
```

The created output.txt is then empty.

Any ideas why? I've been going crazy over this for the past 2 days not figuring out what is happening.

Comment: When will this program terminate?

Comment: @simon was about to ask the same... :-)

Comment: Step 1:  Limit input length. Change to `scanf("%255", word);`  2) check result of `scanf()`, `if (1 != scanf("%255", word)) break;`

Comment: You edited your question to remove ALL the code.  Bad form.   I restored it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to break the infinite loop when std input closed:

```
if (scanf("%s", word) == EOF) break;
```

also you can flush standard output to force writing the results to the output file:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I changed it to !feof(stdin) but now it created an output file with millions of answers (true, false)

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not have an exit condition. I only added one line

```
if(i == 0)
    {
    if (word[i] == '!') return 0;       // <--- added this line
    ...
```

Then the command (similar to yours)

```
test <test.txt >output.txt
```

writes the expected results to `output.txt` after the line `"!"` is read.

Comment: I did this exact modification and it now still creates an output file with millions of results :/

Comment: You changed the question.It said "The created output.txt is then empty.". Now you say "millions of results". Which is it?

Comment: It had no output before, now after the edit it shown lots and lots of answers.

Comment: You changed the asked question to nothing, and I rolled it back. Otherwise it is meaningless.